# Referencing already opened word document in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am using Excel VBA to open a word Template and it populates the template with information from an excel spreadsheet. From there, I have a button on the spreadsheet that I want to then populate another line in the word document whenever it is clicked. The problem I am encountering is that when I run the button macro it just opens up another word document and pastes the button information instead of doing it on the already opened document. I will attach my code below and I believe it is an easy fix I just can't seem to find a way around it.

```
Sub RepairCal()

Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\z003narc\Documents\Gage Lab Form Template.docm")

objWord.Activate

With Selection

   objWord.ActiveDocument.Selection.MoveDown count:=6
   objWord.ActiveDocument.Selection.MoveRight count:=5
   objWord.ActiveDocument.Selection.TypeText Text:="Repair and Calibration"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If your host is Excel, `Selection` is referring to what's selected *in Excel*... but that `With Selection` block isn't doing anything, just remove it. Your life would be easier if you added a reference to the Microsfoft Word type library, and worked with a `Word.Application` and `Word.Document` instead of an `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
With objWord 

   .Selection.MoveDown count:=6
   .Selection.MoveRight count:=5
   .Selection.TypeText Text:="Repair and Calibration"

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you already have the document open when you run this every time?  The way you wrote the code, it will do this:

1) Open new blank Microsoft Word process

2) In the new process, opens the workbook you have chosen

3) Makes the new process the active window

4) `does stuff`

If you want it to attach to the file you *already* have open, you would need to do `GetObject` instead of `CreateObject`. So change:

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

To

```
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

This will attach to the currently open process, then open the workbook in that process. However, it will still open up a fresh copy of that document each time, because that's what you're telling it to do.

Comment: Hi Busse, that is where I was running into trouble, I do not want it to open a new document everytime, but to reference the document that I already have open. Sorry I am fairly new to VBA and am still learning my way around

Comment: Don't apologize, live and learn! I think I misunderstood the question though.